# VS2010 Database Project Back up location

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-backups, database-project

Is there a way to change the back up location for only my database in my database project settings or do I have to do that in a Pre-Deployment script and uncheck the `back up database before deployment` from the `Deployment configuration file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup option uses the SQL Server default backup directory.  You can change that location only by editing the registry.  Unfortunately, you can't set a different backup location for each database.

Location (For SQL 2008)

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer
```

Change...

```
BackupDirectory
```

For more on changing SQL server default paths...
http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1583

If you are feeling adventurous, you could change the registry value in your pre-deployment script and reset it with you post-deployment script.  Use "xp_instance_regread" and "xp_instance_regwrite" to do that.  **USE WITH CAUTION!**

More on that -> http://sqladm.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpinstanceregwrite-syntax.html

If you notice in your deployment script...the code to read the registry entry looks like this...

```
EXEC @rc = [master].[dbo].[xp_instance_regread] N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer', N'BackupDirectory', @dir output, 'no_output'
```

If you are careful, you could read, change, and restore the path during your deployment.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was afraid to have an answer like yours... thx, i'll look into that.